# How to align bootstrap cols like this

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there a  way to fill this white space with red box ? im using bootstrap grids

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following format for this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">Yellow</div>
            <div class="col-md-12">Red</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">Red</div>
            <div class="col-md-12">Yellow</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: im so dumb.. thanks a lot